# How to get the highest and lowest number

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

So i have this set of code which looks like this

```
  for (var i = 0; i < secname.length; i++) {
    description = secname[i].description
    price = secname[i].price_breakdown.display_charges.price
    debugger;
  }
```

What my issue is at the moment is that this passes back 3-4 prices per object.

What ideally i'm wanting is the lowest and the highest price from these with the description. It currently passes back (with the same description) 4 prices before going into the next description.

I would also like to put it into the table i have. i have the prepend code i'm just unsure where to place it.

So tl;dr I have a table, The description name is unique and has 4 prices. I want the highest price and lowest price appended to my table.

Sam

**Edit**

Heres the code

```
                            "CIRCLE": [
                          {
                            "price_secname": "P1",
                            "price_breakdown": {

                              "price_secname": "P1",
                              "vat": 0,
                              "distance_charge": 0,
                              "display_charges": {
                                "price": 35,
                                "sum_fees": "5.25",
                                "formatted_total_price": "&Acirc;&pound;40.25"
                              },

                              "legacy_price": 35
                            },

                            "description": "Circle",
                            "ticket_desc": "Full Price Ticket",

                          },
                          {
                            "price_secname": "P2",
                            "price_breakdown": {

                              "price_secname": "P2",
                              "vat": 0,
                              "distance_charge": 0,
                              "display_charges": {
                                "price": 50,
                                "sum_fees": "5.25",
                                "formatted_total_price": "&Acirc;&pound;50.25"
                              },

                              "legacy_price": 35
                            },

                            "description": "Circle",
                            "ticket_desc": "Full Price Ticket",

                          },
                          {
                            "price_secname": "P3",
                            "price_breakdown": {

                              "price_secname": "P3",
                              "vat": 0,
                              "distance_charge": 0,
                              "display_charges": {
                                "price": 40,
                                "sum_fees": "5.25",
                                "formatted_total_price": "&Acirc;&pound;45.25"
                              },

                              "legacy_price": 40
                            },

                            "description": "Circle",
                            "ticket_desc": "Full Price Ticket",

                          }
                                ]
```

Comment: Is the dataset stored in an array?

Comment: I don't see where you're making any comparison between the prices

Comment: We need to see the data you're looping through. If it's an array you can just use `Math.min`/`Math.max`

Comment: You can try something like this: `var price = secname.map(function(x){ return x.price_breakdown.display_charges.price }); var max = Math.max.apply(null, price); var min = Math.min.apply(null, price);`

Comment: See edit, In debugger they come back as objects

Comment: Is it the display_charges you want to compare? @admitme_sam

Comment: want to compare display_charges.price in each thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just building off Rejesh answer, essentially looping over each object and pulling out the max, min and description.

```
for (var i = 0; i < circle.length; i++) {
    var description = circle[i].description
    var price = circle.map(function(x){ return x.price_breakdown.display_charges.price; }); 
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, price); 
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, price.filter(Number));
    console.log(description)
    console.log("Max: " + max);
    console.log("Min: " + min);    
}
```

Snippet

http://jsbin.com/votoheceha/4/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Any way to ignore 0's?

Comment: If the price is = 0 ignore?

Comment: Yep How would i do that? :)

Comment: @admitme_sam `.toString().replace("0", "")`  put this on the end of your variable

Comment: Sorry, Wasn't clear, Can i get it so the next min if the min is 0? So my numbers are 50, 40 , 35, and 0, Its showing as 50 and 0 but i'd like it to be 50 and 35?

Comment: @admitme_sam Ahh! okay see the changes `Math.min.apply(Math, arry.filter(Number))`